# Is there a way to disable css rules like unchecking them in devtools of firefox does?

Tags: css, browser

Is there a way to reproduce that but using additional css rules ?

[image]

My specific problem is how to disable a framework rule (that i cannot modify or edit) using additional css the same way firefox and chrome dev tools do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think it should be clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might mean is the CSS `unset` or `inherit` keyword. By that, you can rule out   CSS-properties assigned from other CSS sources (that probably aren't your own, e.g. coming from some theme files). `unset` makes it as if it wasn't set in the first place while  `inherit` makes it inherit the parent's property.

Then just define the selector you're targeting and switch off a certain CSS property, e.g.:

```
.foo .bar {
    font-family: unset;
}
```

You might have to enforce that with `!important` in case your selector is less powerful than some other.

Comment: But remeber unset isn't supported by internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling code in css while leaving it in place for possible later use is done by commenting it out. All code between `/*` and `*/` will not be used.

```
/* .foo {
  display:block;
} */
```